# Const robustness of pointer inside a struct and performance

Tags: c, data-structures, const-correctness

I have a struct like this

```
struct S {
    int l;
    double* very_large_data;
}
```

On this struct I want to act upon various functions. In particular there are some function for which I want an instance of S to be read only. However if I define

```
int read_only(const struct S* S_ptr) {
    ...
    *very_large_data = ...   // OK, no error
    ...
}
```

inside the function I can always access and modify the value of data pointed by `very_large_data`. In order to prevent this one can of course modify the struct definition to

```
struct S {
    int l;
    const double* very_large_data;
}
```

in that way is not possible to to modify data even if the structure is passed as non const pointer

```
int write_on_S(struct S* S_ptr) {
    ...
    *very_large_data = ... // ERROR, this is a pointer to const.
}
```

in this way one would be forced to reallocate the pointer to modify the data. This would require possibly very large operations with memory.

Which would be the best design to enforce "logical" const correctness without introducing some costly memory operations?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you can either cast away the const, or if you really, really don't want the user to touch the state, consider using an opaque type with accessors

Comment: The "best way" is likely to use opaque type and don't give the caller access to the internals of the struct.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to solve with an opaque pointer? I do not understand it because it seems to me that one could always call the setter even in the `read_only` functions.

Comment: It depends on what kind of data you are actually storing. For example, if you're storing an array of n elements of x, provide an interface to get a copy of the ith element. That is to say, you should think about the operations on the data, rather than mindlessly typing out "getter/setter".

Comment: However, you should consider what actual tangible benefits (rather than those of metaprogramming) are you going to get from this sort of encapsulation.

Comment: I see thank you for your suggestion. What I still do no understand is how opaque typing would solve my problem. Whatever is my `very_large_data` I would provide an interface to act upon it. Some functions would simply read this data, some other functions will write on the portion of memory. Then my question is: "how to prevent the use of these  latter group of functions in the definition of functions like `read_only`?"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, however in case I do, you prevent it by simply not exposing any functions writing the data to the user.

Comment: Sorrry, I did not explain well. I actually do want to give the user the possibility to writing data, but only  if my pointer to struct is passed without const. Just to mimic ordinary type (i.e. in `func(const int* a)` I cannot modify a but in `func(int* a)` I can).

Comment: Well, you're going to have to write two different functions with different identifiers to do that, because what you're suggesting is called function overloading and C does not have that.

Answer (score 1):

You could always *cast away* the `const` inside your function, i.e.

```
int write_on_S(struct S* S_ptr) {
    double *data = (double *)S->very_large_data;
    *data = 42.0;
}
```

This is valid provided that `very_large_data` did not point to an *actually `const`-qualified object*.

Comment: This isn't really true. C17 6.3.2.3/2. "For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal."  There is no text "otherwise the behavior is undefined", so converting from qualified pointer to non-qualified pointer isn't really covered by the standard. And things that aren't, are by default UB.

Comment: Also see assignment or parameter passing, where attempting a conversion from qualified pointer to non-qualified pointer is a constraint violation.